# Excel macro to populate one cell in a sequence from a given range

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Currently, after I enter a number in cell `A1`, the data in the spreadsheet changes; then I run a macro `macro1` to save it to PDF.
The problem is when I need to enter more than 30 such numbers into the cell, and run the `macro1` 30 times.
Can I get a macro to populate cell `A1` from 1-30 in a sequence and do the `macro1` automatically?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This question is unclear and lacks details enough to be able to answer it. Please [edit] this to include the code of the macro itself and clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make another macro or another code like this (in VBA) :

```
Public Sub runMacro()
    For i = 1 To 30
         ' Body of your macro and set the row number by i
         ' Cells(1, 1) = i    'Enter 1-30 numbers to cell A1
         ' Call pdfMacro      '<pdfMacro> is your current macro
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: In my best guess at interpreting the question, I believe that the OP wants to set `VALUE(A1) = i` each time; the row number doesn't change. Aside from that, this looks like a good answer (or, at least, the beginnings of one).